# Just trying to figure out why this FileNotFound exception is happening

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, io, filereader

[Image showing the error and that the program Could not find file 'N:\20-22_ALevel_CS\George Readhead\NEAExampleEngine\NEAExampleEngine\bin\Debug\Assets\Maps\Startup'.'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwsJQ.png)

[Picture showing the location of the file to be where the program searching when trying to create a StreamReader.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wX5V.png)

I'm just confused as to why this is happening, so I'm not sure if it's a simple and obvious answer or if I should have submitted any code from other parts.

Comment: Aren't you missing an extension on the path? Like `.txt` or `.cs`.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the extension

the file is called `startup.txt` and your code is trying to read `startup`

you should be reading `startup.txt` so add `.txt` to the file path
hope this answer helps